# Suggestions for speeding up vb.net Access query to populate an array

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

```
 Dim Builders As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
    Builders("Provider") = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    Builders("Data Source") = "C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SimpleSQLTest\SimpleSQLTest\dictionary.mdb"
    ' Dim sSQL1 As String = "Select Words, synonym from [Word List];"
    Dim sSQL1 As String = "SELECT lemma, def from [def look-up];"
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim z As Integer
    Using Connection As New OleDbConnection(Builders.ToString)
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sSQL1, Connection)
        Connection.Open()
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

        'reader.Read()
        While reader.Read
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve Word(i)
            ReDim Preserve DeforSyn(i)
            Word(i) = reader(0).ToString
            DeforSyn(i) = reader(1).ToString
            'Form1.TextBox1.Text = reader(0).ToString()
            Form1.TextBox1.Text = reader(0).ToString & " " & reader(1).ToString
        End While
    End Using

    MsgBox(i)
```

---

So trying to speed up the query.  The read of the last item is just to see how long it takes.  I do a different method in VB6 and it loads very quickly.  Trying to load a dictionary that is over 200,000 rows.   Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Definitely a lot of records for an Access DB.  I've read about SPs in Access, but have never tried it. -  http://hubpages.com/hub/Stored_Procedure_in_MS_Access

Comment: May be of interest: http://thedailyreviewer.com/dotnet/view/getrows-equivalent-106118737

Comment: 200,000 rows x 2 columns (or even 10 columns) is not big, and Access should be able to handle it without any problems.

Comment: I'm migrating from a VB6 that pulls this very quickly using a similar style operation.

Comment: Let me add to the chorus that 200K records is not a big deal for Access/Jet/ACE. I've had live apps with 2 to 3 times that number of records in more than one related table, and performance was just fine. Perhaps the problem is with the data interface you're using, but it's certainly not a limitation of a properly-indexed Jet/ACE table. The fact that it works fast in VB6 proves that the problem is not with Jet/ACE.

Comment: the redim statement in the loop was the issue causing it to slow way down.

Comment: So, going back to @Randolph Potter's initial comment, he was talking out his posterior -- converting to a different back end would have had zero effect on performance.

Comment: Thanks for the personal comments, David. I shall look fondly on this thread in future.

Comment: If you say stupid things, you'll get called out on it. I would expect the same in return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redim might be an expensive operation.  Have you tried to start with:

```
select count(*) from [def look-up]
```

And create arrays of the right size before you start retrieving data?

Comment: Also moved my form text out of the loop.  Huge improvement thank you.